# MongoDB Atlas - Unknown Connections spikes from private IPs

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have a MongoDB cluster running on Atlas. We connect each client to MongoDB by passing an `appName` with that we know who connects to the cluster and we can identify them.

At some points, we get a huge connection spike of unknown connections and we can't identify them.

If an alert happens we identify the unknown connections with this script:

```js
  const currentActivities = await db.admin().command({ currentOp: 1, $all: 1 });
  const activeConnections: Record<string, number> =
    currentActivities.inprog.reduce(
      (acc: Record<string, number>, curr: Record<string, number>) => {
        const appName = curr.appName ? curr.appName : 'Unknown';
        acc[appName] = (acc[appName] || 0) + 1;
        acc['TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT']++;
        return acc;
      },
      { TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT: 0 }
    );
```

I tried analyzing the logs and I see a large number of connections from private IPs. These private IPs have (most of the time) an app name set. For example, they are `MongoDB CPS Module`.

It is not super straightforward to analyze the logs so I am not sure which IPs the UNKNOWN connections are. I only count the connections by IP.

Did anybody have a similar problem and some suggestions on how to tackle that?

Thank you

Sandro

Comment: This site focuses on programming questions.  You might try asking the folks over at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did that thanks  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/322966/mongodb-atlas-unknown-connections-spikes-from-private-ips